# How to defaultly set variable inside C struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a struct in C, and need to set a value inside it to 1. This means that for all new structs created off that struct, the stage variable should be automatically 1.
So far I have tried:

```
new_struct->stage = 1;
```

and

```
struct new_struct {
    stage = 1;
}
```

but none of these actually work. Is there a way to do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an `init_struct` function, and call it religiously for every `new_struct` you allocate.  It might look like this:

```
void init_struct(struct new_struct *nsp)
{
    nsp->stage = 1;
}
```

If you allocate an ordinary `new_struct` variable, initialize it by calling `init_struct`, passing a pointer to it:

```
struct new_struct ns;
init_struct(&ns);
```

If you call `malloc` to get a pointer to memory for a brand-new `new_struct`, pass that pointer to `init_struct`:

```
struct new_struct *p = malloc(sizeof(struct new_struct));
if(p != NULL) init_struct(p);
```

The `init_struct` function I've shown only initializes the `stage` member, since that's what you said you were worried about.  Usually it's also a good idea to make sure that *everything* in the structure is cleanly initialized to zero, which you can do by adding a call to `memset`:

```
void init_struct(struct new_struct *nsp)
{
    memset(nsp, 0, sizeof(*nsp));
    nsp->stage = 1;
}
```

(Theoretically that `memset` call might not be adequate for allocating structure members of pointer or floating-point types, but this is a rather esoteric concern, and on any machine you're likely to use today, the `memset` call will be sufficient.)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the struct declaration and initialization into a function:

```
struct new_struct init_struct(void)
{
   struct new_struct s = { .stage = 1 };

   return s;
}
```

or a macro:

```
#define NEW_STRUCT(s) struct new_struct s = { .stage = 1 }
```

and use that everywhere you would otherwise use

```
struct s v;
```

like

```
struct new_struct v = init_struct();

// or

NEW_STRUCT(v1);
```

I would however question why you would need a bunch of structs that all have the same value in one element first place? Isn't there a better way to deal with whatever problem you try to solve with that?